# What is the shell command to send attachment with body?

Tags: bash, unix

Based on my code below I am sending a attachment on the mail but theres no Body, I want to add a body but was not able to do it. Its either the message has body and no attachment or with attachment and no body

```
#!/bin/bash

TmpMailFile=test.mail.msg

FROM="test@test.com"
TO="test@test.com"

uuencode /tmp/test.txt test.txt >> ${TmpMailFile}

SUBJECT="Test Subject"
echo "Test Body" >> ${TmpMailFile}

mail -s "${SUBJECT}" ${TO} -- -r ${FROM} < ${TmpMailFile}

rm ${TmpMailFile}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
mailx -s "$email_subject" $EmailRecipients << EOM 'uuencode $exp_file $exp_file`

Please find the file attached

Message in Body goes here.............

EOM
```